# Development trends of Business apps in WPF now a days

Tags: wpf, winrt-xaml

I have asked this question several time form many developers about the future of WPF in 2015 and in coming years. Someone told me that Microsoft is interested to take this technology in the future also.

Actually i like to develop enterprise and LOB business application in Winforms and now want to move to WPF. Time is short and i need a concrete answer that should i invest my time in WPF or not? If the answer is not then what is the new Microsoft tool to develop business application like Point of sales applications and other large database business applications. I have a keen of new technologies so i don't want to invest my time and money in old technologies. If Microsoft is also not interested in these technologies then i am not also.

So please anyone can tell me that what is the best and new suitable technologies to create business application now a days from Microsoft?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll chime in.

This is a tricky conversation because we are on the verge of Windows 10. Let’s start out talking about Windows 8. WinRT XAML for Windows 8 is certainly not ready for you to use it out-of-the-box for to create a full-featured, LOB application. There are too many things missing like validation, windowing, and advanced binding. The Ent. app was not it's primary mission.

On the other hand, WinRT XAML for Windows 8 is perfectly suited for creating a companion, touch-first app that delivers value to tablet-based or phone-based users who would interact with your app in a more limited way – like reporting or workflow. I talk about this more here:

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-apps-whats-enterprise-to-do.html

WPF is a different story. WPF is proven, right? It totally is. There’s nothing you can dream up that WPF can’t do great. No line-of-business requirement holds it down. It's awesome. What’s more, is that WPF runs on Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, and soon Windows 10. That’s a lot of operating system options.

The future of WPF is quite bright, too. The team is reinvigorated and the improvements slated this year and the new tooling for XAML developers makes it an even better experience. I talk about that more with the WPF team here:

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/11/hey-future-of-wpf.html

WinRT XAML for Windows 10 is different. For one, it’s not going to be an operating system-based system. That means, more like .Net, you just target the framework you require installed and go from there. It is also more fully tooled to compete with the fidelity of WPF XAML to build LOB apps.

But with WinRT XAML for Windows 10 you have to ask yourself how many people will be running Windows 10 because it will not work on previous versions of Windows. Since Windows 10 will offer itself as a free upgrade for the first year, you could argue that many will be running Windows 10, but since the Enterprise version of Windows 10 is not part of that deal, you can only determine that by knowing your IT roadmap. Nobody can do that for you.

All things being equal, if you are simply trying to choose between WinRT XAML for Windows 10 and WPF today, you will choose WPF. Once you have an adequate install base of Windows 10, I think most LOB developers are going to be surprised how tempting an option Windows 10 is. The future of WPF is solid. But the most significant investment into UI technologies at Microsoft is, hands down, WinRT XAML for Windows 10. Does that mean WPF is not future-proof? Of course not. I would choose WPF without any hesitation, as I have done for years.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Anything can be a gamble, especially with Ms. They (and Intel) tend to throw darts at a wall and when one sticks, it marks the current direction for the week.

According to Microsoft WPF never went away. They forget to tell many employees that. For a while XAML was so very WPF like it was almost the same thing, and for a point of sale system, it seems like if you are going a Microsoft direction, XAML would be the better choice. But again, it is almost the same thing; Windows store app with XAML as opposed to desktop app with WPF. But the direction of the week is yes WPF will go forward and even possibly be Ms strategy for cross platform.

But I would also really ask is Microsoft the right choice for your target? I would think heavily about Android.  Not so much just Java, last I looked their roadmap had wpf like functionality targeted for 2024. Or iOS as I don't expect to see Apple sell a cash register anytime soon, so I doubt if they will ever be in the Point of Sale business.

I did a fairly big Point of Sale system a long long time ago. Actually 2 of them. With what I know I would target XAML/Store apps today. But it is about a 51/49 split with Android in my mind. If the customer wanted Android, I would not argue very much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, As i understand you said, its fine to go with wpf/xaml. But here i have another thing in my mind that, cannot we develop business apps in windows store app ? or windows store aap is just for mobile? not for desktop?. So in last just tell me one thing more about winRt, is winRt is just for mobile development? cannot we make desktop apps like we do in WPF/winforms? thanks.

Comment: WindowsRT is dead for the moment (could change again next week). Also, the deployment model for Windows Store apps is ONLY through the store or via a Enterprise Side Loading Certificate for a costs.  You can not make or use Store apps (XAML) the same as desktop apps.

Comment: http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/Windows8LOBDeploymentLsquostoryrsquo.aspx  is the sad story.  I probably would rethink my Store app recommendation. It will cost over /$375 each for you to deploy your application.

Comment: Ohh my God it's dead I just google. So what will be the replacement by Microsoft and what abot my original question for business apps in. net? If I do not choose. net then what tool should I choose to develop business apps of any other company? Is there any other company that provides a perfect tool that has future too?

Comment: I guess the current thinking is to write a web app. I can't think of anything worse (including Store Apps), but that is where scholars have led us. I'm glad I am retired.

Comment: Thankful for your detailed answers. I really wanted to talk with you more but thread is going to be long. I can now conclude that I should stick with windows form for business app(I use beautiful and mature telerik controls) and move to web like asp.net mvc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70534/discussion-between-user3004110-and-spiked3).